Maximum IP Devices On A Switch
There is a large corporate building going up with each door (974 IP based doors) and we are running multi conductor fiber to each device. Can a managed switch (Gigabit) handle the amount of addresses, white listed MAC addresses with approximately 90% bidirectional communications at any given time. The door interface modules only communicate in very short burst of data.

This is entirely dependent on the switch itself. I am not aware of any switch with 900+ ports. A single VLAN probably cannot support that many devices. Whitelisting MAC addresses is sort of pointless from a security perspective.

Since I doubt you have 900+ doors on a single floor. You should be doing a spiderweb deployment. Connect the doors to access switches each floors access switches and to core switches a central location. Each floor will handle a VLAN. Most high end switches can support thousands of devices. You will want multiple core switches.

You are correct about multi floor. We also count one door twice (badge in & badge out). Thank you for the knowledge. We’re running multi mode fiber to each floor. How would you set the IP scheme. Floor One= ###.###.001.(device IP) Floor Two= ###.###.002.(device IP)?

The only advice I am willing to provide as already been provided.  I don't do network design for free, nor do I acquire customers, from anything I do here at Super User.  I also have no desire to have any customers. In other words you should use internal resources within your company to design your network.
